# Private messaging in Django

Tags: django, messaging

I'm looking for a preexisting Django app providing user to user private messaging. I've seen [django-pm](http://code.google.com/p/django-pm/) and [django-messages](http://code.google.com/p/django-messages/), neither of which appear to be in particularly active development. Is there really nothing out there?

Comment: the inbuilt django contrib messages!

Comment: That's intended for messages from the system to a user, not user <-> user. It "allows you to temporarily store messages in one request and retrieve them for display in a subsequent request (usually the next one)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old, but this looks promising [django-postman](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/overview).  I'm about to try it out for a project I'm working on.

I found it here:

http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/messaging/

If you haven't seen it before Django Packages is a great site for finding django apps that do all sorts of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Never Tried it out or anything, but looks promising at first glance.
[django-pm](http://code.google.com/p/django-pm/)

Comment: I saw that one, but it's pretty much inactive. No changes on svn since 2007. [django-messages](http://code.google.com/p/django-messages/) is less inactive, but it's been a year since any movement.

Comment: This might be a lot of work, that you really don't want to do, but you could try to look at some django forum apps and pull the user to user message from that.

Comment: I thought about that, and I'm running on 1.3b1. So I felt that it wasn't worth the hassle. And (famous last words), I'm only looking for something relatively simple, so I'm going to give the roll-your-own method a shot.

Comment: Was about to post the same question. Please let us know when u find/come up with something.

Comment: Always share the rollyourown methods - especially if it's "relatively simple" - someone may built on top of it

Answer (score 1):

old post, but +1 ack:
maybe you help xmpppy...http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/
in documentation to xmpppy remark about privat messages ( http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/irc/howtouse.html)