# Message exchange in Django how?

Tags: javascript, django, django-models

I am working on Django application where users can exchange post-it notes with each other. I had already found two good front-end solutions for it:

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sticky-notes-ajax-php-jquery/demo.php 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/30/jstickynote-a-jquery-plugin-for-creating-sticky-notes/

Could you please, advise me on the Django back-end solution?

Thanks in advance for all the ideas and considerations.

Comment: By "exchange post-it notes" do you mean posting a note that appears in another account? Or sharing a note such that editing one changes the other as well?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear enough. What i mean is user A creates a note and posts it on the "wall" where others can see it but not edit. User A though, can edit or remove the note from the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really that's just a messaging system wherer users can login and leave other users messages which will be displayed as stickynotes

Here are loads of messaging related apps for django:

- http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/messaging/

Plus some specifics

- http://code.google.com/p/django-messages/
- http://code.google.com/p/django-messaging/
- https://github.com/platypus-creation/django-stickynotes
- [Private messaging in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577553/private-messaging-in-django)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Digging in!