# Email User Template Django

Tags: django, templates, messaging

I'm using Django Userena to configure my user profiles. The site works like this: User#1 creates Object#1 on my site. Afterwards, I want to enable other people to message User#1 about Object#1 using Userena's messaging system.

I realize that you can get a user's email like this:

```
{{ object.user.email }}
```

but I dont want to expose my user's emails on the internet and would prefer to use userena's messaging system.

How would you do this? Would I create a link on the page to [userena's write view](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/src/6ff9fdf9c33f7365a7235a789af2e47f47d9c4fa/postman/views.py?at=default#L111), including the username as a parameter?

I have to admit I am pretty lost on how to do this, but as it seems like a common problem, I hope for any good suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: If you want users to be able to message each other, [look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577553/private-messaging-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install userna's messaging framework, by adding `userena.contrib.umessages` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. You also need to add it to your urlconf. For example:

```
(r'^messages/', include('userena.contrib.umessages.urls')),
```

Now, if you go to an url like `/messages/compose/username_1+username_2+username_3/` then a message can be sent to all those 3 users whose username is in URL.

Please have a look at [`urls.py`](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/contrib/umessages/urls.py) and [`views.py`](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/contrib/umessages/views.py) to learn more.

If interested, you should look into [`models.py`](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/contrib/umessages/views.py) as well to know what all models are being used for this.